# how to use Linux lib such as timeval in windows

Tags: linux, cygwin, dev-c++

how to use Linux lib such as timeval in windows
I have installed cygwin and dev c++
I don't like compliling in cygwin
compliling under dev c++ always erro like 
`gettimeofday' undeclared (first use this function)

unfortunately, I don't have enough harddisk space to install a linux or any vitual machine

thanks a lot

Comment: 90 ish pounds for a 1TB hard drive? Linux can be installed on a virtual disc of around 10G easily, so this is probably the best way. You'll need the disc space for something else soon anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use Linux code straight away in Windows, of course.

But it seems you're trying to do this using Cygwin, which should support the Linux/POSIX APIs.

If the error you're getting is a compile-time (and not linker) error, you probably are missing the proper header file:

```
   #include <sys/time.h>
```

These are documented on `gettimeofday()`'s [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday).

Comment: I have added the right header files
My question now is how to associate cygwin and the dev-cpp
I would like to compile and debug my program in dev-cpp using the linux APIs
Is there any way?
come on, help me

Answer (score 0):

after all 
it seems that we cann't use linux lib directly in windows
my cygwin sugffers from all kinds of problems
finally 
I install vmware, a vitual linux machine and done that
which may be not a wise way but a practical one